# Checking solution of differential equation $x''-x'-2x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to figure out how to work out initial conditions. I can do it when there was one C, but now there are two I'm stumped!

So the exercise in the book wants me to check that

$x = C_{1}e^{-t}+C_{2}e^{2t}$

is a solution for

${x}''-{x}'-2x = 0$

and I worked this out, which looks okay I think

$(C_{1}e^{-t}+4C_{2}e^{2t})-(-C_{1}e^{-t}+2C_{2}e^{2t})-2(C_{1}e^{-t}+C_{2}e^{2t}) = 0$

but then it wants me to find the initial conditions using this

$x(0)=10$ and ${x}'(0)=0$

Do I just plug a $0$ into the functions? If so don't I just end up with $x = C_{1}+C_{2}=10$ and ${x}' = -C_{1}+C_{2}=0$

I'm stumped!

Comment: $x'=-C_1e^{-t}+2C_2e^{2t}$, so $x'(0)=-C_1+2C_2$.

Comment: What does the title have to do with the text of the OP?

Comment: Ah ah, no you're not stumped! Check the comment by @vadim123 and solve the system of two equations in two variables $C_1$ and $C_2$. Done!

Comment: Thanks I've corrected it now.